# Running Batch Simulation in Cluster

Tags: c#, cluster-computing, batch-processing, job-scheduling

As a part of my task I have to create a c# code which runs the batch file (already created using another c#) containing a no. of simulations and input parameters, and I want to automate it for possible exceptions and errors with alternate solutions that I'll be giving in the code
Like, currently we have to manually monitor for any failures or errors and have to run the simulations again. So, to avoid that I want to automate the process by including the possible exceptions in the code.

I'm new to this, and so any kind of inputs would be really helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have reviewed following links I found online -

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/quick-create-simulated-device-tpm-csharp

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-parallel-node-tasks

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/quick-run-dotnet

- https://in.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/batchsim.html

- https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2012/04/20/running-scripts-on-a-cluster-using-the-batch-command-in-parallel-computing-toolbox/

-

Comment: Reviewed doesn't mean tried, you hvae to start an approach and test with minimal code and then some users may be able to help you.

Comment: That's nice approach to help !!
Still, as I said I'm new to this, and so don't exactly know where to start from, I know what I want, I'm looking for how to proceed.